# Gas estimation failed: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Tags: solidity, remix, ropsten, gas-estimate

I have two contracts one for defining token and other for crowdsale. I am using remix ide.

```solidity
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract owned {
  address public owner;
  constructor () public {
    owner=msg.sender;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner {
    require (msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }
}

contract EdCoin is owned {
  string public name;
  string public symbol;
  uint8 public decimals = 18;
  uint256 public totalSupply;

  mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;
  mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

  event Transfer (address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
  event FrozenFunds (address target, bool frozen);
  event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

  constructor(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string memory tokenName,
    string memory tokenSymbol
  ) public {
    totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                
    name = tokenName;                                   
    symbol = tokenSymbol;                               
  }

  function _transfer (address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    require(_to != address(0x0));
    require(!frozenAccount[_to]);
    require(!frozenAccount[_from]);
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
    uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
  }

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require (_to != address(0x0));                          
    require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
    require(!frozenAccount[_from]);
    require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                           
    _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function transferN (address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require (_to != address(0x0));  
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;

    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

    return true;
  }

  function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            
    totalSupply -= _value;                      
    emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         
    totalSupply -= _value;                              
    emit Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) public {
    frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
    emit FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
  }

  function distributeToken(address[] memory addresses, uint256[] memory _value) public returns (bool success) {
    for( uint256 i=1;i<addresses.length;i++){
      _transfer(addresses[0], addresses[i], _value[i]);
    }
    return true;
  }

  function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
    balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
    totalSupply += mintedAmount;
    emit Transfer(address(0), address(this), mintedAmount);
    emit Transfer(address(this), target, mintedAmount);
  }
}
```

CrowdSale contract:

```solidity
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

import "./Ed.sol";

contract DappTokenSale {
  address admin;
  EdCoin public tokenContract;
  uint256 public tokenPrice;
  uint256 public tokensSold;

  event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

  constructor(EdCoin _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
    admin = msg.sender;
    tokenContract = _tokenContract;
    tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
  }

  function multiply(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
    require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
  }

  function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
    require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
    require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens);
    require(tokenContract.transferN(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));

    tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;

    emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
  }
}
```

Both contracts have been successfully deployed but while trying to buy tokens it throws error below

```
Gas estimation failed
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction
```

I am using RopstenTest network for testing purposes.

Comment: Your contract seems working on Remix VM. Are you sure that you transferred the tokens to DappTokenSale contract? As an alternative, you can directly deploy contract in your TokenSale contract using tokenContract = new Edcoin(params)

Comment: No i haven't transferred tokens to Sale contract. How to do it?  I deployed Token contract, supplied its address to sale contract while deploying it.

Comment: make following call to Token Contract : 

>>>>>>transferN(tokenSaleAddress, totalSupply) 

from the account that deployed token contract.

Comment: Transferred it but the error is still persisting

Answer (score 0):

There are several `require` statements in your code and it seems that some of them fail.  Try adding error messages to your `require` statements to known which one actually fails:

```solidity
function multiply(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
  require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x, "multiply");
}

function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
  require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice), "value");
  require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens, "balance");
  require(tokenContract.transferN(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens), "transfer");

  tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;

  emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your contracts are perfectly written but i think you do not understand basic token operations.

First of all your token contract have no tokens to give some one as you transferred total supply to your Owner in token contract.

Second:
the statement in TransferN function

```
require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
```

in this case msg.sender is the person who is trying to buy how is balance can be more than the value requested?

If you want to sell your tokens this way you should remove above mentioned require statement and call _transfer from within your transferN. Its not a good approach but it will work.Learn how token work.

```
function transferN (address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require (_to != address(0x0));  

    _transfer(owner, _to, _value);

    emit Transfer(owmer, _to, _value);

    return true;
}
```

Again it is not right approach.